# How could a mobile banking app be hacked?

Tags: account-security, iphone, smartphone

My phone got stolen, and sent back to where it was stolen a day after.
At the moment of stealing, the phone was locked. When I received it back, there was no money left in my bank account.

The Banking app needs my fingerprint or a password to unlock. The passwords used for the banking app and the phone are different.

I assume there's no password caching for banking apps, since the app requires the password every time. Also, the account is most likely blocked if many attempts are made to unlock it.

What are the possible ways the hackers could have cracked into the phone and then the app?

```
My device: iPhone 7 
Banking-App: Sberbank
```

Comment: I think you can clone the phone on virtual machines, then try all the possibilities. It shouldn't work on new Iphone and I don't know if it works for those apps

Comment: With physical access to a device, there are a LOT of ways to compromise it.  Modern mobile device security does a great job of removing the low hanging fruit, but once a dedicated attacker has physical access, all bets are off. File police reports, fraud reports, etc., and treat that phone as if it's a wide open back door for malicious people to use to further attack you.  (It would probably do the most good in a plastic bag, gathering dust as a paperweight in an evidence locker at a police station.)

Comment: *"The Banking app needs my fingerprint ..."* - there are often older fingerprint traces on the phone which are sufficient to reconstruct enough fingerprint in order to fool the fingerprint detection. See [Here Is Your Fingerprint!: Actual Risk versus User Perception of Latent Fingerprints and Smudges Remaining on Smartphones](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=3134600.3134643).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich didn't know that was an option, thanks!